# Как обмениваться с БД?

Tags: html, javascript, php

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос: есть html сайтик. Нужно чтобы он запрашивал данные с БД (php скрипт там их обрабатывает) и пересылает в какой либо форме обратно.
Как их переслать обратно сайту? Или как я понял PHP скрипт должен создать страницу с ответом =( Может я чего то не понимаю? т.к. долгое время работал с Delphi.
Можно ли как то так зделать чтобы PHP обработал запрос и как то переслал данные обратно, и получив их, с помощью JS расставить эти данные по местам =)

Comment: php+mysql  шукай на эту тему и не изобретай велосипед.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**php** - интерпретатор на стороне сервера

**javascript** - это язык для работы с `DOM`-объектами на стороне клиента.

Запрос на сторону сервера можно сделать с помощью команд `javascript`, напр. `ajax` ( используя библиотеку `jQuery` например).

В основном на сторону сервера данные из клиентских запросов попадают в массивы `$_GET` и `$_POST`.

За вывод данных отвечают такие команды `php` как

```
echo "Test";
```

Чтобы у вас получилось то что вы хотите вам нужно разобраться в том как устроен `php` и `javascript` и вообще технология `клиент-сервер`.

Выберете себе пару книг по `php` и `javascript`.

С `БД` уже лучше через `PDO` в `php` работать.

Comment: а вариант типа http запрос --> php обработка --> сохранение результатов в файл (на сервере) и потом с помощью JS открыть этот файл и прочитать возможен?

Comment: поконкретнее можно? что вы там за файл с помощью JS собрались открывать?

Comment: читайте книжки.. хоть php и js не такие уж и сложные, но с разбегу даже их взять не получится... 
вообще схема очень простая:
js.ajax -> http post/get -> php $_GET $_POST -> mysql -> php echo -> js success

Comment: >читайте книжки.. хоть php и js не такие уж и сложные, но с разбегу даже их взять не получится

боюсь, не будут читать. Для меня вообще остается огромной загадкой, почему все эти юные php-погромисты не желают читать книг, или хотя бы элементарно пользоваться гуглом. Ведь спрашивают элементарнейшие вещи, которые описаны в любой книжке по php и 100500 раз разжеваны на всех профильных сайтах

Comment: Я кстати много читаю электронных книг. Просто пока не все понятно и приходиться у кого то спрашивать, к сожалению весь мой круг знакомых программистов пишет десктопные приложения на C или Delphi.
Но вот читая книги и т.д. по вашим-же советам, начинаешь понемногу понимать принципы работы веб, я то привык к написанию десктопных приложений, потому и подход ищу похожий =) Просто написав что то на PHP мне не нравиться перерисовка всего контента по нажатию клавиши "следующая запись в БД" =( Вот и ищу способы обмена данными между страничкой и БД.

Comment: DreamChild
Вот хотел узнать есть такой подход в веб разработке?
html через форму дает запрос на сервер, PHP скрипт обрабатывает запрос и сохраняет данные в файл на сервере (ну к примеру выборку из БД). Можно ли с JS (который у клиента) прочитать этот файл с сервера, вытянув из него нужные данные и расставив их по своим местам на страничке не перерисовывая страничку. =)

Comment: js работает с клиентом. Т.е. получить файл с сервера через js не получится.
В описанной вами ситуации js вообще не нужен. http запрос -> php обрабатывает запрос, сохраняет данные на сервере и ФОРМИРУЕТ html ОТВЕТ(из того же файла к примеру). Если вы занялись вебпрограммированием, забудьте про js на начальном этапе. Все ваши задачи вы можете сделать без него.

Comment: @fStrange ну если убрать запоминание файла на сервере, то получится упрощённое описание ajax.

Answer (score 0):

[@FrancNet](/users/11222/francnet) вы говорите, что много читаете? так вот читайте внимательнее. Вам надо понять, что клиент и сервер - это две очень  разные сущности. JavaScript предназначен в основном для клиента (есть еще Node.js, но вам о нем думать рано), поэтому никакие файлы на клиенте обрабатывать не нужно, не выдумывайте глупостей. Более того, если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то вам даже никаких файлов не надо генерировать на сервере. На сервере обрабатывается запрос, отправленный с клиента, после чего с сервера на клиент возвращаются какие-то данные в любом удобном виде - JSON, HTML, XML. То есть я еще раз хотел бы повторить - если вы хотите сгенерировать файл на сервере чтобы с помощью содержимого этого файла создавать/изменять html-разметку на клиенте, то этого делать НЕ НАДО, это бред сивой кобылы. То, что вам нужно, называется AJAX. Что это такое, и как с ним работать, ищите в Гугле, уж надеюсь, воспользоваться поисковиком и прочесть (а еще лучше, понять) пару несложных статей у вас ума хватит. Что касается того, что "привык к написанию десктопных приложений, потому и подход ищу похожий" - об этом лучше забудьте, в web-программировании немного другие принципы. Про Delphi лучше тоже забыть (было бы совсем здорово, если бы вы и про php забыли, а взялись за какой-нибудь язык поприличнее, но это уж воля ваша)

Comment: @DreamChild А чем Вам delphi-то не угодили? CGI/FastCGI на них вполне можно писать... Под виндами, разумеется. Ну или на free pascal, если не винды.

Comment: В начале карьеры программиста (1990) я взял книгу C++, с дискетой на которой редактор с компилятором, установил, ввел код "Hello word" (101% точно как в книге) и компилятор выдал ошибку =). Начал учить pascal, о чем сейчас очень сожалею, С++ намного уровней выше Pascal,Delphi. Borland забил на Delphi. Но все что заказывают писать это 1С подобные программы, складской учет, бухгалтерия. Во общем не интересно мне это все стало в один момент. Вот и начал изучать сферу веб. HTML вроде освоил нормально, сам руками могу все писать, PHP так себе еще, ну а JS только начал познавать =)

Comment: @alexlz претензии к Delphi и так уже многократно озвучивались, не хотел бы повторяться.

Comment: @DreamChild я сам их не люблю, но это не отменяет указанных мной вариантов.